# Validate if exist array in jQuery with operators?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an array response from ws and I'm looking for an exact object inside of the response, so when the object is not found, jQuery gives me an error. I tried to validate with the || and ?: operators but it does not respect it, and it continues to give me the error.

This is an example of my response:

```
    [{
        "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
        "schema_id": 301,
        "language_id": 18,
        "content": "04 mar. 2019"
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
        "schema_id": 601,
        "language_id": 18,
        "content": "Todo terreno  de 5 puertas con distancia corta entre los ejes"
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
        "schema_id": 701,
        "language_id": 18,
        "content": "Capacidad para siete pasajeros"
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
        "schema_id": 1101,
        "language_id": 18,
        "content": "16 bocinas BOSE, subwoofer y sonido envolvente"
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
        "schema_id": 1301,
        "language_id": 18,
        "content": "AM/FM, Audífonos Inalámbricos, pantalla táctil y pantalla a color"
    }]
```

I am looking inside the array like this:
First attempt

```
table.append(
  $("<tr>")
           .append(
                '<td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>'+
                '<td>Body style</td>'+
                '<td>'+ response.find(characteristic => characteristic.schema_id == 601 ).content || " " +'</td>'
            ),
```

Second attempt

```
table.append(
$("<tr>")
  .append(
         '<td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>'+
         '<td>Body style</td>'+
         '<td>'+ response.find(characteristic => characteristic.schema_id == 601 ).content ? response.find(characteristic => characteristic.schema_id == 601 ).content : " " +'</td>'
),
```

When the object is not found, I expect null value in the td, but I give an error and the table is null.

Comment: Can you expand on this? "but I give a error and the table is null" The first attempt seems fine, other than the closing `</td>` missing when content is found. (remember your order of operations)

Comment: @KevinB I have this erorr in console `response.find(...) is undefined` and the table body is without row even when it has already found other objects

Comment: Ah, so none of your problems are related to the majority of the code you provided. Are you sure `response` is an array?

Comment: Yes, it is, check the example, my real response is with 200 objects, so I need make the search inside him.

Comment: Ah, so it's just not finding anything in your array. well, your code for it is fine, it's likely that the value simply isn't in the array. You can't do `.content` on undefined, so you'll have to test the result of the `.find` instead.

Comment: yes, some values aren't  in the array and I need validate that, but my validation with "||" or "?:"  doesn't work

Comment: well, no, it's not that those don't work. ***it's failing before that is even reached!*** They're irrelevant to your problem. You can't access a property on undefined without an error being thrown.

Comment: I have the same error with response.find(characteristic => characteristic.schema_id == 37401) || " ", I know that is imposible use an attribute from an undefined element

Comment: that should have given you a different error, if any error at all. Afterall, you removed the part that was throwing an error.

Comment: https://github.com/you-dont-need-x/you-dont-need-jquery

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using find and then checking for a match:

```js
response = [{
    "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
    "schema_id": 301,
    "language_id": 18,
    "content": "04 mar. 2019"
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
    "schema_id": 601,
    "language_id": 18,
    "content": "Todo terreno  de 5 puertas con distancia corta entre los ejes"
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 771004720190304,
    "schema_id": 701,
    "language_id": 18,
    "content": "Capacidad para siete pasajeros"
  },
];

table = $('table');
for (e of [701, 401]) {
  let item = response.find(({ schema_id }) => schema_id == e);
  table.append(
    $("<tr>")
    .append(
      '<td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>' +
      '<td>Body style</td>' +
      '<td>' + (item ? item.content : '') + '</td>'
    ),
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: it's not a plain object, it's an array.

Comment: @msg right, the contents are plain objects, but the response is an array, and does in fact have a find method. You very well could have also just used the filter method without needlessly wrapping it in a jquery collection.